# shader and cook-torrance cannot output texture

Tags: opengl-es, textures, fragment-shader, vertex-shader, opengl-es-lighting

I am completely new to opengl es shader and cook-torrance,
the following shader only output red, no texture color processed for ambient light and point light.
the cube is for testing,no shader applied to it, the right side rocket with texture with no output,just red color. Any opengl es guy can help?
[image: no texture only red]no texture only red
[image: original texture before apply cook-torrance]original texture before apply cook-torrance and output by gl_FragColor =texture2D(texture,vertTexCoord.st).rgb*vertColor;
But what make CookTorance() below fail?

fragment shader

```
 #ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
precision mediump int;
#endif

#define PI 3.14159265

//copper
uniform vec3 diffuseColor = vec3(0.75164,0.60648,0.22648);
uniform vec3 specularColor = vec3(0.256777,0.137622,0.086014);
uniform float F0 = 0.8;
uniform float roughness = 0.1;
uniform float k = 0.2;
//uniform vec3 lightColor = vec3(1, 1, 1);
uniform sampler2D texture;


varying vec4 varyvertColor;
varying vec3 ecNormal; //eye normal
varying vec3 lightDir;
varying vec4 varyambient;
varying vec4 varyspecular;
varying float varyshininess; //0.1
varying vec4 vertTexCoord; 

varying vec4 vposition;

vec3 CookTorrance(vec3 materialDiffuseColor,
    vec3 materialSpecularColor,
    vec3 normal,
    vec3 lightDir,
    vec3 viewDir,
    vec3 lightColor)
{
    float NdotL = max(0, dot(normal, lightDir));
    float Rs = 0.0;
    if (NdotL > 0) 
    {
        vec3 H = normalize(lightDir + viewDir);
        float NdotH = max(0, dot(normal, H));
        float NdotV = max(0, dot(normal, viewDir));
        float VdotH = max(0, dot(lightDir, H));

        // Fresnel reflectance
        float F = pow(1.0 - VdotH, 5.0);
        F *= (1.0 - F0);
        F += F0;

        // Microfacet distribution by Beckmann
        float m_squared = roughness * roughness;
        float r1 = 1.0 / (4.0 * m_squared * pow(NdotH, 4.0));
        float r2 = (NdotH * NdotH - 1.0) / (m_squared * NdotH * NdotH);
        float D = r1 * exp(r2);

        // Geometric shadowing
        float two_NdotH = 2.0 * NdotH;
        float g1 = (two_NdotH * NdotV) / VdotH;
        float g2 = (two_NdotH * NdotL) / VdotH;
        float G = min(1.0, min(g1, g2));

        Rs = (F * D * G) / (PI * NdotL * NdotV);
    }
    return materialDiffuseColor * lightColor * NdotL + lightColor * materialSpecularColor * NdotL * (k + Rs * (1.0 - k));
}

void main(){
vec3 direction = normalize(lightDir);
//vec3 normal = normalize(ecNormal);
vec3 normal = -normalize(ecNormal);



vec4 vertColor =  varyambient +
        vec4(CookTorrance(texture2D(texture,vertTexCoord.st).rgb*varyvertColor.xyz,
        varyspecular.xyz*specularColor,
        vposition.xyz,
        direction,
        normal,
        varyvertColor.rgb),1.0);



gl_FragColor = vertColor;


}
```

is there any error in the above cook-torrance?
please help on it.

the vertex shader

```
uniform mat4 modelviewMatrix;
uniform mat4 transformMatrix;
uniform mat3 normalMatrix;
uniform mat4 texMatrix;


attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec4 color;
attribute vec3 normal;

attribute vec4 ambient;
attribute vec4 specular;
attribute float shininess;

attribute vec2 texCoord;

varying vec4 vposition;
varying vec4 vertColor;
varying vec3 ecNormal;
varying vec3 lightDir;


varying vec4 varyambient;
varying vec4 varyspecular;
varying float varyshininess;
varying vec4 varyvertColor;

varying vec4 vertTexCoord;



void main() {
  // Vertex in clip coordinates
  gl_Position = transformMatrix * position;
  vposition = transformMatrix * position;

  // Vertex in eye coordinates
  vec3 ecVertex = vec3(modelviewMatrix * position);

  // Normal vector in eye coordinates
  ecNormal = normalize(normalMatrix * normal);


  varyambient=ambient;
  varyspecular=specular;
  varyshininess=shininess;

  varyvertColor=color;

  vertTexCoord = texMatrix * vec4(texCoord, 1.0, 1.0);

}
```

Comment: You have to simplify the shader code to find the issue. Do you "see" the texture if you do `gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture,vertTexCoord.st).rgba;`? (Use a tool to introspect you application. e.g [RenderDoc](https://renderdoc.org/))

Comment: what are the GLSL compile and link logs saying?

Comment: yes, the second graph is from `gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture,vertTexCoord.st).rgba`

Comment: is RenderDoc for OpenGL ES? I need write it in OpenGL ES,sorry

Comment: no error, everything fine, the CookTorrance() write wrongly only?